# Saving pandas dataframe as .csv, converts score to date

Tags: python, excel

This is probably a really dumb question.

I have a dataframe that has a column containing scores of a soccer game (e.g. 1-2). When I save the dataframe using df.to_csv, and open the .csv file in Excel afterwards, the scores are given as date (e.g. 1-2 is now 1st Feb).

I realize this is an issue within Excel probably, since when I open the file in Notepad, the scores are as they should be.

So my question is, how best to handle it? Is there an option in Python where I can save the .csv in such a format that the score isn't converted to a date? Or is it something to be tackled in Excel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save your file as text (.txt) instead of .csv, Excel shouldn't re-format it.

This might go against your specific needs, if .csv is necessary. But if not, you can achieve the same result (in the sense of delimitation and headers) by opening the text file from Excel's File Menu, selecting 'Delimited'. 
Then, if in python you are saving your .txt file with a comma delimitation, de-select the 'Tab' option and select 'Comma'..